# Kivy app crashes while importing modules like requests, etc, I have also mentioned then into the .spec file but still the app crashes

Tags: python, kivy

Kivy app crashes while importing modules like requests, etc, I have also mentioned then into the .spec file but still the app crashes. I have also uncommented the INTERNET line in the .spec file.
Thank You.

log file:

[INFO   ] Logger: Record log in /home/dheeraj/.kivy/logs/kivy_20-08-11_43.txt

```
[INFO   ] Kivy: v1.11.1
[INFO   ] Kivy: Installed at "/home/dheeraj/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] Python: v3.8.1 (default, Jan  8 2020, 22:29:32) 
[GCC 7.3.0]
[INFO   ] Python: Interpreter at "/home/dheeraj/anaconda3/bin/python"
[INFO   ] Factory: 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] Image: Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[ERROR  ] Input: MTDev is not supported by your version of linux
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dheeraj/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/input/providers/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    import kivy.input.providers.mtdev
  File "/home/dheeraj/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/input/providers/mtdev.py", line 84, in <module>
    from kivy.lib.mtdev import Device, \
  File "/home/dheeraj/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/lib/mtdev.py", line 28, in <module>
    libmtdev = cdll.LoadLibrary('libmtdev.so.1')
  File "/home/dheeraj/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 451, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/home/dheeraj/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libmtdev.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[INFO   ] Window: Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[INFO   ] GL: Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] GL: Backend used <sdl2>
[INFO   ] GL: OpenGL version <b'3.0 Mesa 20.1.2'>
[INFO   ] GL: OpenGL vendor <b'Intel Open Source Technology Center'>
[INFO   ] GL: OpenGL renderer <b'Mesa DRI Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)'>
[INFO   ] GL: OpenGL parsed version: 3, 0
[INFO   ] GL: Shading version <b'1.30'>
[INFO   ] GL: Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] GL: Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] Window: auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] Window: virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] Text: Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] GL: NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] Clipboard: Provider: sdl2(['clipboard_xclip', 'clipboard_xsel', 'clipboard_dbusklipper', 'clipboard_gtk3'] ignored)
[CRITICAL] Cutbuffer: Unable to find any valuable Cutbuffer provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
xclip - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'xclip'
  File "/home/dheeraj/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    mod = __import__(name='{2}.{0}.{1}'.format(
  File "/home/dheeraj/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/core/clipboard/clipboard_xclip.py", line 17, in <module>
    p = subprocess.Popen(['xclip', '-version'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/home/dheeraj/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854
```

, in **init**
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
File "/home/dheeraj/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)

xsel - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'xsel'
File "/home/dheeraj/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/core/**init**.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
mod = **import**(name='{2}.{0}.{1}'.format(
File "/home/dheeraj/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/core/clipboard/clipboard_xsel.py", line 16, in 
p = subprocess.Popen(['xsel'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
File "/home/dheeraj/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in **init**
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
File "/home/dheeraj/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)

[INFO   ] ProbeSysfs: device match: /dev/input/event11
[INFO   ] ProbeSysfs: unable to found provider mtdev

```
[INFO   ] ProbeSysfs: fallback on hidinput
[INFO   ] HIDInput: Read event from </dev/input/event11>
[INFO   ] Base: Start application main loop
[WARNING] stderr: Exception in thread HIDInputMotionEventProvider:
[WARNING] stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/home/dheeraj/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
[WARNING] stderr:     self.run()
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/home/dheeraj/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
[WARNING] stderr:     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/home/dheeraj/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/input/providers/hidinput.py", line 656, in _thread_run
[WARNING] stderr:     fd = open(input_fn, 'rb')
[WARNING] stderr: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/input/event11'
[INFO   ] WindowSDL: exiting mainloop and closing.
[INFO   ] Base: Leaving application in progress...
```

Comment: Please provide crash logs and config file contents. Without them, it is hard to tell what the issue is

Comment: Sir how can I show then to you

Comment: It is added in the question sir